# From a List<String> to a Map<Label, PasswordField> using java 8

Tags: javafx, arraylist, java-8

Is possibile to generate an HashMap using stream and collector? 
I've tried with something like:

```
 myList.stream()
.map(Label::new)
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), PasswordField::new))
```

but it obviusly doesn't work, I've tried other solution, but without success.
Have you some advidce?

Comment: A side note, using `Label` as a key is dangerous. `HashMap` should have immutable keys, and `Label` isn't one.

Answer (score 5):

The [`PasswordField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/PasswordField.html) class only has a default constructor which means `PasswordField::new` will not work as it's equivalent to `(Label l) -> new PasswordField(l)`. instead the value mapper should be `(Label l) -> new PasswordField()` or simply `l -> new PasswordField()`;

Comment: …which leads to the question, why the `Label` is created in a `map` step instead of within the `toMap` collector, i.e. `myList.stream() .collect(Collectors.toMap(Label::new, s -> new PasswordField()))`…

Answer (score 1):

As correctly mentioned by Aomine, [PasswordField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/PasswordField.html) has a default constructor and hence, `PasswordField::new` as mentioned in your code won't work. Use `l -> new PasswordField()` instead:

```
myList.stream()
    .map(Label::new)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), l -> new PasswordField()));
```

Comment: Sorry to say it this frankly, you did not add anything useful besides Aomine's answer.